AttributeError: module 'aioboto3' has no attribute 'client' when using openeew
I'm trying to use the openeew library in a Python script, but I'm encountering an error that I can't resolve.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
from openeew.data.aws import AwsDataClient

data_client = AwsDataClient('mx')

start_date_utc = '2018-02-16 23:39:00'
end_date_utc = '2018-02-16 23:42:00'

records = data_client.get_filtered_records(
  start_date_utc,
  end_date_utc
  )```

When I run that script, I get: AttributeError: module 'aioboto3' has no attribute 'client'.

I'm running this in a virtual environment in VSCode with Python 3.9.6, Aioboto3 version 12.4.0, and openeew 0.5.0. Any help would be much appreciated!




I pip installed openeew and expected this simple script to run off the bat, but ran into this error. I tried doing a bunch of random version changes based off github copilots advice, to no avail. 

